# Comment utiliser correctement le pluriel de "aucun"?

Tags: accord, pluriel

J'ai vu hier une publicité où il était affiché à un moment l'expression "aucun**s** frais". La présence de ce "s" m'a surpris, et je suis donc allé vérifier en ligne si ce n'était pas une erreur. Et, à ma grande surprise, il existe effectivement un pluriel à ce mot. J'ai donc continué mes recherches afin de déterminer comment correctement utiliser ce pluriel.

En tant qu'adjectif indéfini, d'après [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aucun):

> aucun en tant qu’adjectif prend la marque du pluriel quand il est utilisé avec un nom qui n'a pas de singulier ou qui change de sens au pluriel.

Mais je n'arrive pas à totalement comprendre cette règle. En effet, sauf si je me trompe, je pense que l'on écrit "ça n'a aucun sens", et pas "ça n'a aucuns sens". Ou alors je fais une erreur sur le mot "sens" en lui-même.

Je crois comprendre la façon d'utiliser le pluriel de aucun quand il est un pronom indéfini, mais je reste assez incertain sur ce point aussi.

Comment correctement utiliser le pluriel de "aucun"?

Comment: "sens" dans "ça n'a aucun sens" *est* au singulier.

Comment: @dim Ah, j'ai cru que "sens" fonctionnait de la même façon que "frais". C'est peut-être ça que je n'ai pas compris.

Comment: En effet, ces deux mots ne fonctionnent pas pareil. On ne peut pas dire "un frais" (dans le sens de "dépense d'argent"). C'est toujours "des frais". En revanche, "sens" peut être singulier ou pluriel.

Comment: Il y a une différence entre les mots qui finissent par un *s* même au singulier (comme *sens*), et les mots qui n'ont pas de singulier (ou dont le sens change comme dans ta définition). Du coup la réponse à ta question est dans la définition que tu donnes :)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Je comprends. Pour le coup j'ai cru que, comme on pouvait dire "du sens", "sens" était invariable dans ce sens. Je comprends mieux du coup. Je ne serais néanmoins pas contre une explication pour l'utilisation de son pluriel quand "aucun" est un pronom indéfini. De ce que j'ai compris, "aucun" prend un "s" quand il renvoie à plusieurs entités, et n'en prend pas quand il ne réfère vraiment à un ensemble ne contenant pas d'éléments? J'ai vraiment eu du mal avec les exemples du wiki.

Comment: De toute façon, "*du*+ nom" se comporte comme du singulier (*du rhum artisanal*). Je ne connaissait pas bien "*aucun*" en tant que pronom indéfini, mais le wiktionnaire est assez clair, je vais rédiger une réponse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En ce qui concerne l'adjectif indéfini, la définition est correcte.

Il ne faut pas confondre les mots qui finissent par un *s* même au singulier (comme *sens*), et les mots qui n'ont pas de singulier ou dont le sens change au pluriel (comme *des frais*).

Pour *Aucun* en tant que pronom indéfini, ça dépend de si tu t'attendais à un ou plusieurs éléments (lorsque tu n'en trouve aucun). Ça dépend de comment tu conjugues le verbe, selon ce que tu veux dire.

En suivant les exemples du [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aucun#Pronom_ind.C3.A9fini):

- On aurait pu attendre **des** soldats, mais :

  > **Aucuns** ne **vinrent** à notre camp
- On a cherché ne serait-ce qu'**un** cartésien qui pense ça, mais :

  > **Aucun**, parmi les cartésiens, ne **dit** que l’âme est incapable de se modifier elle-même.

Comment: D'accord, j'avais le doute pour ce dernier point, mais j'avais finalement bien compris pour le pronom indéfini. Merci pour ta réponse et tes commentaires clairs!

Answer (score 1):

Une autre façon d'utiliser *aucun* au pluriel est lorsqu'il est synonyme de *quelques uns*:

> D'aucuns pensent cela.

Answer (score 0):

**Réponse rectifiée**

**Aucun**, suivi d'un nom, constitue un déterminant indéfini quantifiant nul, celui-ci est généralement invariable en termes de nombre, sauf dans les cas où le nom qui le suit désigne, par le sens, une pluralité, et c'est le cas ici avec le nom **"frais"**.

Comment: Pourquoi dis-tu que "frais" est au pluriel?

Comment: @Frank Je le dis parce que le mot frais a deux acceptions, dans celle où il désigne des "dépenses", il n'existe pas de singulier, et ce 's' est inhérent à sa morphologie, et ironiquement, c'est le seul élément dans toute ma réponse qui soit correct, cette dernière remonte à 6 ans, et je viens de la mettre à jour !

Comment: Ah oui, effectivement, ça marche pour _des frais_ (dépenses), j'avais plutôt en tête: _il fait frais_.

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour, j'ai réagi avant de me renseigner. J'ai osé téléphoné à la banque concernée. La réceptionniste qui avait un gros doute aussi m'a expliqué la règle. C'est très perturbant... et j'ai pris le risque de passer pour une imbécile !

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/22407)