# "sans faille" ou "sans failles"

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, orthographe, pluriel

Le Wiktionnaire français donne un exemple pour l'expression idiomatique "sans faille" comme suit:

> Son raisonnement est sans faille. ([Graphie "faille", Nom commun 1, 2. Défaut, premier et unique exemple.](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faille))

Il n'y a pas de référence écrite pour cette phrase. Quand j'ai lu un jour la méditation grothendieckienne, dite "Récoltes et Semailles", j'ai trouvé plein de phrases qui ajoutent un "s", c’est-à-dire que l'auteur dit "sans failles" au lieu de "sans faille". Je donne un exemple:

> Ce ne sont pas ces dons-là, pourtant, ni l'ambition même la plus ardente, servie par une volonté sans failles, qui font franchir ces "cercles invisibles et impérieux" qui enferment notre Univers.

Si vous chercherez dans le même document, vous verrez que cette orthographe est la règle dans ce livre et pas l'exception.

Une enquête "googilienne" m'a donné des résultat pour les deux variantes. Certes, au niveau du son, il n'y a pas de différence. Quand même, je voudrais savoir un peu quelle variante est à utiliser et quand.

Peut-être que le "Bon Usage" ou vous-même avez une directive comme dans le cas pour "la main" et "les mains" (voir la question [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28437/se-prendre-en-mains-singular-or-plural)).

Comment: On peut facilement voir en traduisant les termes vers l'anglais, qu'il peut y avoir une différence de sens entre les deux. Dois-je donner la traduction pour la montrer? Ou est-ce interdit? Je ne sais pas....

Comment: Pourquoi interdit? Faites ce que vous voudriez.

Comment: Le mot faille dans sans faille est un adverbe. Faire quelque chose sans faille: not fail to do something. unfailingly; Mais le mot faille dans sans failles veut veut dire sans cassure (géologie: a fault) ou p.ex. sans point faible (informatique). "No faults" ou "no flaws" aussi. Et puis, c'est un tissus aussi. Un raisonnement sans failles, no flaws in reasoning. ou bien: faultless reasoning. C'est dans le Larousse.

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/170/quand-faut-il-mettre-un-pluriel-apr%c3%a8s-un-mot-indiquant-labsence-dun-%c3%a9l%c3%a9ment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Un raisonnement cohérent

Si l’on désire évaluer une démonstration mathématique, il est entendu que **la moindre faille** dans le raisonnement entraînera l’invalidation de la démonstration dans son état *(dans certains cas, on pourra la rendre acceptable en la modifiant plus ou moins ou en y ajoutant certains cas, mais parfois elle devra simplement être abandonnée comme cul-de-sac)*. Notons aussi qu’en général, ceux qui s’y connaissent en mathématiques s’entendront tout à fait sur la nature inexacte d’un raisonnement : la faille sera la même pour tous. On parlera donc, pour une bonne démonstration mathématique, en mettant l’emphase sur l’absence complète de faille, d’un...

> raisonnement **sans faille.**

Les mathématiques sont un peu un cas limite de rectitude de raisonnement. Un raisonnement se penchant sur d’autres sujets pourra s’approcher plus ou moins de cet idéal, selon que les évidences sont plus ou moins convaincantes ou absolues.

Dans un domaine d’investigation plus difficile, par exemple la re-création en linguistique de la langue indo-européenne, on pourra accepter quelques zones grises et présomptions, car la tâche est immense et la connaissance de plusieurs éléments égarée dans l’abîme des temps préhistoriques. Certaines reconstructions peuvent se montrer plus cohérentes que d’autres et l’on pourra admirer le nombre d’écueils évités lors du processus. Il me semblerait possible alors de spécifier, pour un tel cas, que la reconstruction est bâtie sur un...

> raisonnement **sans failles,**

...car on attend naturellement de ce genre de spéculation qu’elle se fonde sur davantage d’axiomes, sur un certain nombre d’hypothèses incertaines, possiblement non-vérifiables, et sur certains choix qui peuvent être éclairés sans être forcément strictement objectifs. Tout ceci imposera une certaine fracturation intrinsèque à la construction finale, même si tous les raisonnements subséquents s’avéraient cohérents.

---

#### Une ferme volonté

> Ce ne sont pas ces dons-là, pourtant, ni l’ambition même la plus ardente, servie par une volonté **sans failles**, qui font franchir ces « cercles invisibles et impérieux » qui enferment notre Univers.

Ainsi qu’une construction logique difficile et comportant des zones d’ombre voit se multiplier les conclusions possibles et poindre l’impossibilité d’obtenir le fin mot d’un problème, la volonté voit son action se déployer sur un réel d’une extrême complexité et elle s’exprimera de différentes manières selon les circonstances ou les individus, même lorsqu’elle sera d’une exemplaire fermeté.

Par exemple, une volonté sans compromis pourrait aussi bien choisir un retrait temporaire stratégique *(que d’aucuns décriront comme lâcheté)* qu’une attaque perdue d’avance *(l’inconscience pourrait aussi expliquer ce genre de choix)* ou une trève *(ce n’est pas forcément baisser les bras, mais les opposants ne manqueraient sûrement pas de l’indiquer)*.

Je crois qu’une ferme volonté n’est jamais exempte d’erreurs, et que toute volonté, aussi monolithique soit-elle, doit parfois lutter contre le doute. Dire d’elle qu’elle est...

> sans failles

...revient à dire qu’elle est particulièrement solide et stable, et d’une remarquable assurance dans l’adversité.

Similairement, on pourrait *(devrait ?)* utiliser le pluriel pour une route **sans cahots**, parce que quelques rares cahots ne suffiront habituellement pas à justifier de lui retirer son statut de route particulièrement agréable à parcourir en véhicule.

---

Selon la nuance recherchée, un auteur pourra privilégier le singulier ou le pluriel. Cependant, tous les auteurs ne tiennent pas forcément compte de ce genre de subtilité, et leurs choix peuvent sûrement refléter un autre type d’analyse ou de méthodologie que celui présenté ci-dessus, dont entre autres le recours à la très honorable ressource linguistique du *Trésor de la langue française* à [faille², substantif féminin](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faille), où **seul le singulier** est présenté.

Si l’on se penche sur d’autres mots introduits par *« sans »* et exprimant le degré zéro de la quantité, cependant, on s’attendrait au final qu’il y ait une certaine gradation allant du singulier au pluriel¹. Par exemple :

> Le singulier est *(ou peu s’en faut)* la seule solution possible :
>
> - Il s’est présenté **sans chandail** à l’église.
> - Elle a passé la nuit **sans feu.**
> - Un crayon **sans mine.**
> - Avancer **sans bruit.**
>
> Le pluriel est de mise :
>
> - Une nuit **sans étoiles.**
> - Une forêt **sans conifères.**
> - Un cactus **sans épines.**
> - Une eau **sans impuretés.**
>
> Un cas particulier, fonction du style de société envisagé :
>
> - Un couple **sans enfants** *(dans une société où la fertilité est grande, encouragée, glorifiée)*;
> - Un couple **sans enfant** *(attendu dans une ville de Chine, où un couple ne peut légalement avoir qu’un seul enfant, on pourra aussi l’utiliser dans la plupart des sociétés occidentales contemporaines, où la natalité est en forte baisse et où le nombre d’enfants uniques a beaucoup augmenté depuis quelques générations).*

Quelques autres cas particuliers proposés en commentaires par [jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/1109) :

> - Il y voit **sans lunettes** → *les monocles n’étant plus vraiment à la mode aujourd’hui, l’outil que l’on porte pour corriger la vision est à peu près exclusivement désigné au pluriel : des lunettes. Au singulier, ça désigne [différents autres objets](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lunette).*
> - Une chemise **sans manches** → *les chemises, chandails, blouses, manteaux et autres vêtements de forme similaire que l’on dépose sur les épaules viennent habituellement avec une paire de manches, ou avec simplement des bretelles et aucune manche. Les versions exotiques à une seule manche sont une exception rare. Puisque la présence impliquerait une paire, il semble logique de marquer l’absence au pluriel.*

Dans la lignée des lunettes qui ne sont que plurielles, on trouve aussi un exemple signé Émile Zola, qui se permet de surcroît le luxe de mettre *aucunes* au pluriel, dans *Le Docteur Pascal*, paru en 1893 :

> Qu’allaient-ils devenir, **sans ressources aucunes**?

<sub>J’en profite pour recommender la question [Comment utiliser correctement le pluriel de “aucun”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24058/comment-utiliser-correctement-le-pluriel-de-aucun) pour d’autres avis et exemples.</sub>

---

¹ <sub>On pourra citer à ce sujet *Le bon usage*, qui indique :</sub>

> <sub>Pour certains usagers, la **négation** est incompatible avec la notion de pluriel. En réalité, le nom peut être au singulier ou au pluriel, selon qu’il serait au singulier ou au pluriel dans la construction positive correspondante.</sub>

<sub>Suivent de nombreux exemples de  grands auteurs, dont :</sub>

> <sub>- Le navire roulait sous un ciel **sans nuages.** —Un voyage à Cythère, Charles Baudelaire</sub>
>
> <sub>- Faute de **galères,** nous manquons **d’épices** —Salammbô, Gustave Flaubert</sub>

Comment: Quelques autres exemples: *il y voit sans lunettes*, *une chemise sans manches*, *une maison sans fenêtres*...

Comment: @jlliagre Ce sont de bons exemples. J'en ai cependant mis plusieurs autres dans un sujet qui n'est pas exactement celui-ci. Je les laisse donc dans votre commentaire en attendant de penser autrement. Je crois qu'ils ont leur place, mais je me suis déjà passablement étendu. Je crains de lasser.

Comment: Merci bien pour la réponse détaillé @Feelew !

Comment: @jlliagre Je profite de la remontée du sujet pour finalement inclure vos exemples. Merci!

Answer (score 3):

Le choix me semble assez subjectif, cependant je me guide (plus ou moins consciemment) du principe suivant : je choisis la version au singulier lorsque les objets désignés n’existent pas, et la version au pluriel lorsqu’ils existent mais sont temporairement absents.

Par exemple « sans enfant » s’emploiera plutôt pour désigner la situation d’un couple qui n’a pas d’enfant. Alors que « sans enfants » désignera plutôt la situation d’un couple qui a envoyé ses enfants chez leurs grands-parents pour profiter de vacances ou d’un dîner à deux. Ainsi : « Venez profiter d’une soirée sans enfants ! » mais « Situation familiale : veuf, sans enfant ».

De même :

- « c’était une nuit sans étoiles » mais « imaginez un univers sans étoile »,
- « j’y suis arrivé sans problème » mais « une journée sans problèmes »,
- « les naturistes ont construit une société sans vêtement » mais « je me suis retrouvé sans vêtements ».

Bien entendu, lorsque le pluriel a un sens différent du singulier, c’est la sémantique qui l’emporte. Ainsi, on écrira toujours « sans papiers » pour désigner le défaut de documents administratifs d’identité, et « sans papier » pour désigner l’absence de feuille A4 dans l’imprimante.

Comment: Bien que je n’approche pas le problème de cette exacte manière, je trouve intéressant que vous exposiez votre façon de faire et approuve que chacun prenne le temps de réfléchir pour trouver un point de vue qui lui convienne. +1

Answer (score 2):

J'aurai eu tendance à utiliser la règle de base qui est de se dire si c'est sans faille, c'est qu'il y a 0 faille, donc pas de "s" vu que ce n'est pas au pluriel.

Comment: Merci! Peut-être que l'auteur fait la confusion parce qu'il a des racines allemandes. En allemand, on dit par exemple "lückenlos" et on ne dit jamais "lückelos" ce qui est faux (ici "Lücken" est le pluriel de "Lücke"). Aussi, "ohne Probleme" est beaucoup plus courant que "ohne Problem" même si la dernière version n'est pas nécessairement faux. Dans l'expression "fehlerlos", on n'observe pas la différence parce que le pluriel et le singulier de "Fehler" sont les mêmes.

Comment: Je dirais de quelqu'un qui a perdu la mémoire qu'il est *«sans souvenirs»*. Bien qu'il ne reste aucun souvenir, donc le nombre zéro, singulier en français, le nombre de nos souvenirs est habituellement si considérable que je perçois l'absence en contraste avec la notion strictement plurielle de la collection que chacun traîne.